# Share front matter between translations

Tags: hugo

I have a Hugo site with translations per file, using page bundles.

So the About page looks like this:

```
- about
  - about-image.jpg
  - index.en.md
  - index.nl.md
  - index.fr.md
```

The problem is that I have to repeat the non-i18n front matter in all of the .md files.

For example, `date`, `tags`, et cetera.

Is there a way in hugo to define the (basic) front matter once, and have translations only contain overrides needed for i18n?

Comment: Better question Dyve, why do you want only 1 front matter? If you have multiple languages, your meta data would be best to be different, title, description, etc. So then the question becomes, well maybe you only want to share some front matter, such as taxonomy tags, but don't you want them language specific? Or maybe not? So the question is, maybe more data on the problem being solved? (Note: I do develop solely with Hugo and solely on multi-language sites, so I'm really asking a specific question to see if I can assist).

Comment: Late reply, but yes, it would be the non-i18n-specific info. Taxonomy, date published, et ecetra.

Comment: So, this is the only way I know of doing that, at this time, https://gohugo.io/content-management/front-matter#target-specific-pages isn't a bad idea (manually targeting), never tried it (from M. Inam) but, you could also create a page layout (this would be HTML) and then have a page bundle - with the base language front matter as the index.and then depending on language, "foo.es.md" or whatever, range through and collect the rest. I'd have to psuedo code it when I have the chance. It's a concept and maybe not worth it...

Answer (score 1):

You can define the default language in the config file of the site.
Then, you set the strings that do not need to be translated only into the translation file of the default language, and you do not define them in the other files.

As the translations are missing, Hugo will default to the default language (if defined in the config file).
https://gohugo.io/content-management/multilingual/#missing-translations

Answer (score 0):

Hugo now brings with it front-matter cascade param which you can use to make descendant pages or even translation pages like

```yaml
cascade:
- _target:
    kind: page
    lang: en
    path: /blog/**
  background: yosemite.jpg
- _target:
    kind: section
  background: goldenbridge.jpg
title: Blog
```

Learn more here https://gohugo.io/content-management/front-matter#front-matter-cascade